# iOS Native Maps URL scheme multiple pins

Tags: ios, cordova, maps, pins

I am using PhoneGap to build applications for iOS and Android.

I want to open the native map application on iOS with multiple pins. I am able to open the native map on iOS device using their Maps URL scheme using a ?q=lat,long parameter

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Is it possible to open the native maps app and showing multiple pings instead of only one?

I have tried enough to search for it but there isn't enough documentation to answer my question.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Create an MKMapItem for each pin you want to display, save the MKMapItems to an array, and then use openMapsWithItems:launchOptions: to send the array to the Maps app. The Maps app will display a pin for each item in the array.

I have not used this myself, but it's from Apple's documentation at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKMapItem/openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not using native Map SDK for iOS. I am using PhoneGap framework